# Converter implementation in Python: class versus module?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, architecture, python, code-quality

I've written a [little library](https://github.com/SamuelMarks/doctrans/tree/b3d764a) that uses the builtin [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) library to convert between functions, docstrings, argparse [`.add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument), `class`es, and [soon] more.

Stubs look something like this, with *ir* referring to 'intermediate representation'; i.e., a common internal data-structure that everything parses to and emits from:

```
def argparse_to_ir
def class_to_ir
def docstring_to_ir
def function_to_ir
# Actually had roundtrip ones also
# like `def argparse2class`
```

Similarly:

```
def ir_to_argparse
def ir_to_class
…
```

Earlier today I refactored these for readability and usability. One I reworked into a module called `ir.py`, and renamed the functions so you would do `import ir` followed by `ir.from_argparse`.

The other I tried the more `class`-based OO style, had a base [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC) `class` with `to_argparse`, `to_class`, &etc.; and specialised with a new `class` for each type that just created a new `def __init__` with different parameters (based on input). So now you do:

```
ArgparseTransformer(argparse_ast, **common_kwargs).to_class()  # `.to_argparse()`
ClassTransformer(class_def_ast, **common_kwargs).to_class()    # or `.to_method()`
```

PS: There is no need for a unified interface to infer what the input type is.

Which approach is better, the [explosion of] `class`es one, or the one which requires knowledge of the internal data-structure?

PPS: Open to alternative 3rd+ choices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up removing all `class`es in my codebase—outside of [`unittest.TestCase`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)—and just using `def`s:

```
In [1]: import doctrans.transformers
In [2]: doctrans.transformers.__all__
Out[3]: ['to_argparse_function', 'to_class', 'to_docstring',
         'to_file', 'to_function']
In [4]: import doctrans.docstring_struct
In [5]: doctrans.docstring_struct.__all__
Out[6]: ['from_class', 'from_class_with_method', 'from_function',
         'from_argparse_ast', 'from_docstring', 'from_docstring_parser']
```

Leaving me with an SDK like:

```
transformers.to_file(
    transformers.to_function(
        docstring_struct.from_class_with_method(
            class_with_method_and_body_types_ast, "method_name"
        ),
        emit_default_doc=False,
        function_name="method_name",
        function_type="self"
    )
    filename='classy.py', skip_black=False)
)
```

(obviously I need a better name than `docstring_struct`)

Which works reasonably well…